# NFS issue Behind iptables in Centos 7

Tags: iptables, nfs, centos7

We have setup iptables which allows TCP/UDP port 111 2049 32769 32803 892

.. i made following changes in /etc/sysconfig/nfs

RPCMOUNTDOPTS="-p 892"

and

/etc/sysctl.conf

fs.nfs.nlm_tcpport=32803

fs.nfs.nlm_udpport=32769

as per given in redhat documentation to run nfs behind firewall in Redhat/Centos 7

ref - https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/nfs-serverconfig.html

still nfs is not binding to this provided port and takes any random port which restrict any client to connect to nfs because of iptables .. we can not stop iptables ..

tried with rpc.mountd -p 892 this command but seems to be not working ..

o/p - rpcinfo -p

program vers proto   port  service

```
100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
100024    1   udp  46390  status
100024    1   tcp  38521  status
100005    1   udp  20048  mountd
100005    1   tcp  20048  mountd
100005    2   udp  20048  mountd
100005    2   tcp  20048  mountd
100005    3   udp  20048  mountd
100005    3   tcp  20048  mountd
100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
100021    1   udp  40472  nlockmgr
100021    3   udp  40472  nlockmgr
100021    4   udp  40472  nlockmgr
100021    1   tcp  35454  nlockmgr
100021    3   tcp  35454  nlockmgr
100021    4   tcp  35454  nlockmgr
```

any help regarding to this world be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Well, /usr/lib/systemd/system/nfs-mountd.service calls rpc.mountd with a $RPCMOUNTDARGS option which differs from RPCMOUNTDOPTS in /etc/sysconfig/nfs.

There's another service called nfs-config.service which preprocess NFS configuration and puts it's output to /run/sysconfig/nfs-utils and RPCMOUNTDOPTS translates to RPCMOUNTDARGS.

The nfs.service though it does not recall nfs-config when a stop/start or restart is used so the config from /etc/sysconfig/nfs does not update /run/sysconfig/nfs-utils.

The solution is simple, run 'systemctl restart nfs-config' before restarting nfs.service.

Comment: I tried systemctl restart nfs-config and it worked perfectly .. i really banged my head as this was not mentioned in redhat documents .. thanks alot for your explanation & quick response .. :)